# Using "import" vs. "from X import"

Tags: python-import

I'm working through Head First Python, and there's an example:

```
from datetime import datetime

odds = [  1,  3,  5,  7,  9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19,
     21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39,
     41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59 ]

right_this_minute = datetime.today().minute

#if right_this_minute in odds:
    #print("This minute seems a little odd.")
#else:
    #print("Not an odd minute.")
```

Now if I substitute "import datetime" for the "from datetime import datetime", the interpreter gives me an error:

> right_this_minute = datetime.today().minute
>   AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'today'

I don't understand why the "from datetime import datetime" works, but "import datetime" does not.  I've gone through a number of stackoverflow Q&A's about this, but I'm obviously missing something.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there are two "things" called `datetime`: the module and a class defined by the module.

The two import options you use have different behaviours.

When you run:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

the first is the module, the second is the class. Python imports only one class (`datetime`) from the module. From then on, Python will understand `datetime` to refer to the class.

When you run:

```
import datetime
```

you import the whole module, so Python will understand `datetime` to be the module. To access class `datetime`, you need to use `datetime.datetime`.